# Unable to find apache common uploads library when hosting on OpenShift

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, openshift

I am trying to host my application on OpenShift. When I try to upload a file, this error message is shown:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Ljava/util/List;
    com.bios.controller.UploadServlet.processRequest(UploadServlet.java:62)
    com.bios.controller.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:114)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.40 logs.
```

But it works on my localhost when I run the files in NetBeans. And I imported the Apache Tomcat 7.0.34 in my lib folder on NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by using incompatible versions of Tomcat locally and in OpenShift.

It's surprising though, because the version numbers only differ by a small minor version number.

But try using the exact same version of Tomcat (7.0.40) locally.

Comment: Oh! How can we change our Tomcat version to 7.0 40. Our current version is 7.0 34 if Im not wrong. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We use Maven to build your project in OpenShift so I would add the declaration in the pom.xml for the mail servlet.

You can also place the jar for the library in the *lib* directory of your git repo for the OpenShift project. Don't forget to do a "git add ." after you add it.

For either method above you will need to do a git commit and then a git push to get the change to take effect.